# Calling a provider method outside the widget tree

Tags: flutter

I am new to the use of Providers in Flutter.

I have a class called CambiarFotoPerfil where I need some functions to upload files to a remote web server.

This is the class structure

```
        class CambiarFotoPerfil extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _CambiarFotoPerfilState createState() => _CambiarFotoPerfilState();
        }
        
        class _CambiarFotoPerfilState extends State<CambiarFotoPerfil> {
    ...
 

        void _upload(File file) {
        if (file == null) return;
        setState(() {
          _textoInfo = "Subiendo foto al servidor...";
        });
        String base64Image = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
        String fileName = file.path.split("/").last;
    
        http.post(phpEndPoint, body: {
          "image": base64Image,
          "name": fileName,
        }).then((res) async {
          print(res.statusCode);
          setState(() {
            _textoInfo = "Foto del perfil actualizada";
            miImagen = fileName;
          });
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          print("Nueva foto del perfil:"+fileName);
          prefs.setString('foto', fileName);
    
          cambiarFotoUsuario();
    
        }).catchError((err) {
          print(err);
        });
      }
...
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        
        var usuarioProvider = Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context);
    
        return Scaffold(
    ...
```

I would like to update usuarioProvider inside _upload(File file) as follows:

```
  var usuarioProvider = Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context);
  usuarioProvider.setimagen(fileName);
```

I am not getting any warning in the editor, but once executed the app, there is an error thrown:

```
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree
```

What is the proper procedure to call a provider function outside the widget tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a provider's value and not listen to it, you should pass

> listen: false

So, something like this should work for you.

```
 var usuarioProvider = Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context, listen: false);
```